System.CalloutException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
I'm perfoming a HTTP GET callout to an external production site URL , using Postman I get the response. However, while making callout from Salesforce, it gives the following error:
System.CalloutException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Here is my code:
public static HttpResponse API_Connector(String FullURL) {        

 HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();       

 request.setEndpoint(FullURL);       

 request.setMethod('GET');       

 request.setTimeout(60000);       

 Http http = new Http();        

 HttpResponse responseObj = http.send(request);       

 System.debug('Response ----->>>' + responseObj);       

 return responseObj;   

 }

Am I missing something else? What could be the issue?

Postman uses your local network configuration to resolve endpoints, while Salesforce can only use public DNS CNAME records. In other words, based on your description, it is likely that the endpoint you are trying to reach is accessible only on your computer, a private network, a proxy, or a VPN, or some combination of these configurations, might otherwise be IP address whitelisted/blacklisted, or has some other configuration that prevents public access. In order to access your data through Salesforce, a network administrator will need to expose the DNS CNAME on the public Internet.
To confirm that this is the case, try the following command in a terminal or command prompt:
nslookup endpoint.tld 8.8.8.8

Where endpoint.tld is the domain name of the server you're trying to reach, and 8.8.8.8 is one of Google's primary DNS servers. If this command returns an error like:
*** dns.google can't find endpoint.tld: Non-existent domain
Server:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8

Then you'll need to talk to that endpoint's network administrator to enable access to the public Internet. Even if this command works, however, there may be other factors at play, such as requiring a proxy or updating a whitelist/blacklist configuration, so contacting an administrator is probably the best course of action.

Your observation is accurate. I could only retrieve the response in Postman when connected to the CISCO VPN using my credentials. Therefore, I'd appreciate any suggestions you might have in light of this information.

@Manoj You'll need to work with your CISCO network administrator to provide public access to the resource. We can't help you any further from this point.
